# Can JAXB store the class name in the XML so that the the deserialize code doesn't need knowledge of the class?

Tags: java, xml-serialization, jaxb

It seems the standard approach for deserializing JAXB XML is to specify the package name when creating the context.  Then, JAXB looks up the class based on the root element:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.foo");
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Object o = u.unmarshal(new StringReader("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"     standalone="yes"?><MyJaxb>..."));
```

I'm looking for a more flexible approach where I don't have to specify the package name and could still deserialize any object.  This would be as simple as JAXB storing the package in the XML, but I can't seem to find out how to do this.  I can write the code to do it myself but that would be unpleasant.  It would like JAXB to do it, if possible.  BTW, I am not using schemas, just Annotations and marshal/unmarshal.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can not deserialize "any" object with pure JAXB. You have to specify either packages (where `ObjectFactory.class` will be sought) or list of classes like `JAXBContext.newInstance(Class1.class, Class2.class, Class3.class);` That's how jaxb works, it's a part of agreement. 
If your tasks are wider that that, e.g. building java classes from arbitrary xml data structure - it's also possible, but you have to be a bit more concrete - what do you mean under "more flexible approach".

Comment: I want the ability to deserialize any object in my classpath, e.g.:  Object o = u.unmarshal(...); without having to specify every possible package and continuously update the list as I add classes with new packages.  All that is needed is to store the package name in the XML.  I think GSON does this.

Comment: @Andrew. Deserialize and do what? That's was the question. You cant do much with Object in Java, but passing it to JS can do significantly more.

Comment: There are plenty of things you can do with Object (e.g. reflection), and that's what I need.  So looks like my solution will be adding the package name to the XML.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add more than one package when you get the instance of the jaxbcontext object. You can add as many packages as you want like below.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.foo.package1:com.foo.package2" );
```

however, I am not sure how you are gonna use it if you deserialize it into an Object instance?
Are you not gonna use what you have just deserialized?

Also Unmarshaller is not a thread safe class if your application is a multithreaded one.

Comment: I'm receiving the objects via jax-rs, then passing on to services that know how to handle them.  Good to know I can supply multiple packages, but I think that might be a maintenance issue.

Comment: If you just want to place the package names into a properties or config file. You can use the above again and define whatever package you need to in that config file so you dont need to compile each time you need to add new packages. is that what you want to do?

Comment: I could do that but then every time I add a new class I have to update that file.  A build script that updated it automatically would solve that but don't want to have to do that.  It seems so simple and obvious I can't imagine that JAXB doesn't have a better solution.